# How to add some custom animation when Scroll with caroufredsel?

Tags: jquery, slideshow, scroller, caroufredsel

I want to add some custom animation when the thumbnails scroll. From example when the user clicks on the *next* button I want for the thumbnails that leave the screen to Fade out and the thumbnails that appear on the screen Fade In.

From the examples I know that this is the function to use:

```
 onBefore: function( data ) {}
```

### Fiddle link

**[Here is a Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ignaciocorreia/F5MW7/)** without the custom animations.

### Example

**[Something similar to this.](http://coolcarousels.frebsite.nl/c/45/)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I manage to animate Fade and Size but there is a bug yet. The images to not come back to visible.

### Added:

```
var defaultCss = {
    opacity: 0,
    width: 0,
    height: 0
};
var selectedCss = {
    opacity: 1,
    width: "77px",
    height: "77px"
};    
var scroolItems = 6;
```

### And:

```
scroll: {
            items: scroolItems ,
            duration: 1000,
            onBefore: function( data ) {
                data.items.old.find('img').animate(defaultCss);
                data.items.visible.eq(scroolItems ).find('img').animate(selectedCss);
            }
        }
```

### [Demo link](http://jsfiddle.net/ignaciocorreia/F5MW7/6/)